# What is the difference between -exec with '{}' ';' and -exec with {} /;?

Tags: 11.04, execute-command

While trying my hand at writing some bash scripts I've come across various usage of the -exec parameter.  In my context, I'm using it after the find command.

[This guide](http://www.museum.state.il.us/ismdepts/library/linuxguides/abs-guide/moreadv.html) states to use {} /; after the exec in order to pass the file name and to escape the ; so that command properly terminates.

[This forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11156301&postcount=2) shows the use of '{}' ';' instead of {} /;.

I tried out both methods on Ubuntu 11.04 and only the one with the single quotes is working correctly.  Is there a difference between Linux versions which causes this?  Are they interchangeable?  Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell may assign the sequence `{}` a special meaning (depending on the type of shell and even if you are inside a shell script or not). To avoid this, you may either enclose it in quotes `'{}'` or escape it like so: `\{\}` (you need to use a backslash `\` instead of a forward slash `/` like you did in your question).

Also note that the usual error message if you do it wrong (for instance, if you use `;` instead of `\;`) is:

`find: missing argument to -exec`

See also the corresponding section in [`find`'s manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

Comment: Can you explain "depending on the type of shell and even if you are inside a shell script or not"? [find(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html) does say "Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a \`\') or quoted to protect them from expansion by the shell," but that seems wrong of `{}`. Are there shells that treat `{}` specially? Brace expansion doesn't affect empty `{}`. [Experts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) seem [not to quote it](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/313200/posts-by-a-user-containing).